# Convert Sink to Graph(SinkShape) in Akka Streams?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have something like this:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("actorSystem")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val (ref: ActorRef, publisher: Publisher[(String, String, String)]) =
  Source.actorRef[(String, String, String)](bufferSize = 1000, OverflowStrategy.fail)
    .toMat(transferFTP(_))(Keep.both)
    .run()

def transferFTP(data: (String, String, String)): Sink[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = {
  // ...
}
```

In every example I have read, `toMat()` takes a `Sink` as a parameter, but the compiler expects `Graph[SinkShape[(String,String,String)], NotInferedMat2]`.

Answer (score 4):

[`toMat`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#toMat[Mat2,Mat3](sink:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SinkShape[Out],Mat2])(combine:(Mat,Mat2)=%3EMat3):akka.stream.scaladsl.RunnableGraph[Mat3]) does take a `Sink`. A `Sink[(String, String, String), _]` is a `Graph[SinkShape[(String, String, String)], _]` (in other words, the former is a subclass of the latter). One of the problems is that you're passing in a `Sink[ByteString, _]` instead. Also, you're expecting a `Publisher[(String, String, String)]` when the materialized value of your `Sink` is a `Future[IOResult]`.

The following is an example in which the types align, thus making the compiler happy:

```
val tupleToByteString: ((String, String, String)) => ByteString = ???

val transferFTP: Sink[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = ???

val (ref: ActorRef, sink: Future[IOResult]) =
  Source.actorRef[(String, String, String)](bufferSize = 1000, OverflowStrategy.fail)
    .via(Flow.fromFunction(tupleToByteString)) // alternatively: .map(tupleToByteString)
    .toMat(transferFTP)(Keep.both)
    .run()
```